# Why C-0(zero) in insert mode is not working?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I have mapped some shortcuts to help me in insert mode and one of them is not working.

```
" Go to end of line on insert mode
inoremap <C-e> <C-o>$
" Go to beggining of line on insert mode
inoremap <C-0> <C-o>0
" Go to beggining of expression in insert mode
inoremap <C-b> <C-o>^
```

The `C-e` and `C-b` is working fine. They go to end of line and first non blank char as expected, but the `C-0` is just inputing the char `0` in the text.

Edit:
I'm using MacOs, NeoVim 0.4 in iTerm 2.

If I run the command `:verbose imap <C-0>` it shows what I configured.

Comment: Are you sure, your vim actually sees the `<c-0>`? Try a different key first and let us know if you are using Vim in the terminal or gvim and what OS you are using.

Comment: I've added the info on the question and I've tried to add to `<c-q>` for example and it worked as expected.

Comment: Seconded. You can, in Insert mode, type `Ctrl-V` before `Ctrl-0`. That way, if `Ctrl-0` is actually emitting anything you'll get a visual indication. (Disable the mapping first, though.)

Comment: Note: https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5

Comment: @BLayer when I do this I get the characters `^@` in my text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506764

Comment: If you see `^@` inside your text, this hints, that Vim does not recognize the key, but just enters ASCI NUL inside your buffer. That means, Vim can **not** detect your `<C-0>` key